# Change appearance rows in WPF ListView c# window

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

In my windows application I defined a window with a list. There are items in this list based on the binder (for the moment I put in the items programmatically).

```
<ListView x:Name="event_list" IsEnabled="False">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Type}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>

var row = new { Type = "type", Description = "description" };
event_list.Items.Add(row);
```

Lets say I want to change the 3rd row and make the font weight bold, how do I achieve this?

Clearly, the following doesn't compile:

```
event_lits.Items[2].FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
```

Because the `Items` propperty returns only the strings I put in, not the view object of the row itself.

Notes for eager answerers: 
 In a wpf window, a ListView is [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview(v=vs.110).aspx) class, not [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx) class (the reason why 9/10 google searches on this topic fails).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an `ItemContainerStyle` with a `DataTrigger` that binds to a property of the data object:

```
<ListView x:Name="event_list" IsEnabled="False">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBold}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Type}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

**Sample data:**

```
event_list.Items.Add(new { Type = "type", Description = "description" });
event_list.Items.Add(new { Type = "type", Description = "description" });
event_list.Items.Add(new { Type = "type", Description = "description", IsBold = true });
event_list.Items.Add(new { Type = "type", Description = "description" });
```

In WPF you are generally not supposed to set properties of the visual containers in the code-behind.

Comment: I totally agree with your conclusion. But this was really helpful.